# spring boot application error due to some server issue?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, hive, swagger-ui

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
\[2m2023-12-08T10:52:33.212+05:30\[0;39m \[31mERROR\[0;39m \[35m1572\[0;39m \[2m---\[0;39m \[2m\[           main\]\[0;39m \[36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              \[0;39m \[2m:\[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) \~\[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13\]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357) \~\[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13\]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156) \~\[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13\]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124) \~\[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:966) \~\[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619) \~\[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at com.device1.component1.Component1Application.main(Component1Application.java:12) \~\[classes/:na\]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179) \~\[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13\]
... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Servlet \[jsp\] in web application \[\] threw load() exception
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:89) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:3215) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:67) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:108) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:66) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:305) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:216) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Class \[org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet\] is not a Servlet
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:869) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:805) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:84) \~\[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5\]
... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet and jakarta.servlet.Servlet are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:865) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15\]
... 33 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```xml
           <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
                     <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `mvn dependency:tree`? You appear to have an incompatible version of Apache Jasper on the classpath.